# I want a regular expression that only matches domain names with one period in them

Tags: regex, url

I want it to catch things like `somedomain.com/folder/path`, but not something like `domain.sub.other.com`. The regex I have so far is almost complete, it just doesn't sift out the multi-domain urls:

```
^(.*)://(?!(.{2,3})\.(.*)(.{2,3})(.*)
```

Is there any way to sift out on multiple periods?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.{2,3}`, you want something like this: `[^.]{2,3}` - this excludes the period (no need to escape as it has no special meaning in this context in a regular expression) from that particular match. Overall you'd have something like:

```
://[^.]+\.[^.]{2,3}(/.*)?
```

Except obviously you're missing things like *.info by doing that....

Comment: Note that `.` *doesn't* have special meaning inside a character class, so you don't need to escape it. It's not a bad habit though, and doesn't do any harm.

Comment: That's why I love SO - never knew that, though it makes perfect sense. I've learned something. :)

Comment: One word of warning on the country code or three letter top level domain assumption, we now have to contend with .name, .info and anything else ICANN gets paid for these days </snark>

Comment: It seems to me that you could just swap in `+` for the `{2,3}` range bit and then four-plus-character TLDs (don't forget good old .museum) would no longer be a problem: `://[^.]+\.[^.]+(/.*)?`

Comment: @SkryneSaver - yes, as I mentioned in the answer. :)

Comment: @Garrett - yes, simple to remediate, wanted to highlight the issue with this sort of thing. :)

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that is working given a variety of test scenarios:

```
^(.*)://([^.]+)\.([^(\?|/|\r|\n|\.)]+)((/|\?|$)+)(.*)$
```

Here, the 2nd to the last group is matching against a potential forward slash, question mark or end of string, working together with the group before it which does not allow matches which include '.'

So the final effect is that it only matches URLs with a two-part domain such as 'domain.com' and there aren't any limits placed on string length.